# Resizing images in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, image-scaling, image-size

In smarty there is the imagesize function which you can pass it a height and a width and it will scale it down until the first dimension property is meet.

E.g. if you have an image that is `5000x3000`

and you pass the function `width=500 height=150`

you will end up with an image that is `500x300`

You can also pass the function `crop=true` and it will crop the image at the dimension that does not fit to make it fit the dimensions, but that cuts off part of the image.

I am wondering if there is a way to make it scale the image down until both dimensions are met, It then fills the remaining area with a transparent background centering the image.

so you would end up with your actual image scaling down to `350x150` it would then fill the left and right with 75 pixels of transparency so your whole file is `500x150`

if an image is passed that is smaller than the given dimensions the same process would take place with the transparent pixels filling in the remaining space.

Does smarty have this ability? or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I think it has not such a ability.

Comment: you can always center it with css

Comment: We need the images the same size for nivo slider, so css centering won't work

Comment: for on-the-fly image editing, u could check out this http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such function.

The only function there is, is [html_image](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.image.tpl), which will automatically insert width and height to the img-tag depending on the actual image size.

But none the other way around.

You can however write your own [plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl), which could give smarty the ability to scale images.